# no es una funcion en vueJs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Hola amigos me da un error con este codigo.

```
data() {
    return {
      stock_grap: [],
}
    methods: {
       mostrar(){
         axios.get('/articulos').then(response => {
           response.data.forEach(element => {
             this.stock_grap.push(element.stock)
           });
         })
         console.log(this.stock_grap)
         alert(this.stock_grap)
       },
```

Y aqui me lanza este error, de que response.data.forEach no es una función.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta diciendo que forEach no se puede aplicar a response.data. Esto porque itera cada elemento de un array y al parecer `response.data ` no lo es. Quizás necesite verificar